# Is a point contained in a-little-bit-more than the map bounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

It's easy to check if a point (e. g. a marker) is inside the map's current bounds:

```
map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())
```

Is there a natural way to **check if a point is inside the map's current bounds enlarged by 10% on each side ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option (you can also expand the bounds along the diagonals):

1. capture the bounds when it is first set using `google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce` on the "bounds_changed" event.
2. expand it by 10% in each direction (N, S, E, W).
3. create a new `google.maps.LatLngBounds` object
4. use the new "expanded" bounds for the `.contains` check.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  var initBounds = map.getBounds();
  var initRect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: initBounds,
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    fillColor: 'red'
  });
  // extend bounds
  var newN = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
    1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getNorthEast().lat(), initBounds.getCenter().lng())), 0).lat();
  var newS = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
    1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getSouthWest().lat(), initBounds.getCenter().lng())), 180).lat();
  var newE = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
    1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getCenter().lat(), initBounds.getNorthEast().lng())), 90).lng();
  var newW = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
    1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getCenter().lat(), initBounds.getSouthWest().lng())), -90).lng();
  var expandedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(newS, newW),
    new google.maps.LatLng(newN, newE)
  );
  var expRect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: expandedBounds,
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    fillColor: 'blue'
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/193Lg531/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var initBounds = map.getBounds();
    var initRect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: initBounds,
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      fillColor: 'red'
    });
    // extend bounds
    var newN = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
      1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getNorthEast().lat(), initBounds.getCenter().lng())), 0).lat();
    var newS = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
      1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getSouthWest().lat(), initBounds.getCenter().lng())), 180).lat();
    var newE = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
      1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getCenter().lat(), initBounds.getNorthEast().lng())), 90).lng();
    var newW = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(initBounds.getCenter(),
      1.1 * google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(initBounds.getCenter(), new google.maps.LatLng(initBounds.getCenter().lat(), initBounds.getSouthWest().lng())), -90).lng();
    var expandedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(newS, newW),
      new google.maps.LatLng(newN, newE)
    );
    var expRect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: expandedBounds,
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      fillColor: 'blue'
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used:

```
var bnd = map.getBounds();
var bnd2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(1.1 * bnd.H.H - 0.1 * bnd.H.j, 1.1 * bnd.j.j - 0.1 * bnd.j.H),
    new google.maps.LatLng(1.1 * bnd.H.j - 0.1 * bnd.H.H, 1.1 * bnd.j.H - 0.1 * bnd.j.j)
);
bnd2.contains(marker.getPosition())
```

Comment: Do not use undocumented properties (bnd.H.j, bnd.j.j, etc), they can and do change with every release of the API. Also realize that your solution will only work in that particular area of the world.

Comment: Why would they only work in that particular area @geocodezip ? If [x1, x2] is the longitude range, I just enlarge this range by 10% on each side, so that the longitude range is slightly bigger. Where in the world would this technique fail ?